# How to send Xcode project via email

Tags: ios, xcode, email

I am trying to attach an Xcode project to an email and send it to someone. I cant attach the file and an error shows up saying: The file size is 0 bytes. I don't want to use dropbox because it only shows the files, but the person cant run the project. Is there a way I can send the full project and the person receiving the app will be able to run the project and not just be able to see the individual files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply zip the folder your project is in.

Navigate to the folder that contains your .xcodeproj file, and zip that folder using "compress" as shown below. Make sure you zip the folder **containing** the .xcodeproj, the projects files, tests, etc. do not just zip the files which are located in the folder with the same name.

[image: How to compress project]